# What are some easy-to-remember prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, big-list

This is a question without much mathematical value, but since I don't immediately see an answer on Google I thought I'd ask anyway ... I'm looking for some largeish (> 10,000) easy-to-remember primes, like palindromes (313), numbers with decreasing digits 54321 (not a prime), etc. The primary purpose is for computer programs, where they are useful for hashing and the like.

What's your favorite, if you know any?

Comment: [The smallest prime greater than $10000$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NextPrime%5B10000%5D) is $10007$.

Comment: Nineteen $1$'s = $1111111111111111111$ is a prime.

Comment: Sorry, what makes 65537 easy to remember? @Tito: love it, thanks!

Comment: The prime $2^{16}+1=65537$ is the biggest _Fermat prime_ known so far. My example is called a [_repunit prime_](http://oeis.org/A004023) (only nine are known yet). P.S. I remember some of my Spanish, and I think "gato" means "cat". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia's [list of prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers) includes "palindromic primes"

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741

and "palindromic wing primes"

101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 11311, 11411, 33533, 77377, 77477, 77977, 1114111, 1117111, 3331333, 3337333, 7772777, 7774777, 7778777, 111181111, 111191111, 777767777, 77777677777, 99999199999.

Answer (score 7):

My personal favorite prime number is [Belphegor's prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belphegor%27s_prime):
$$1\underbrace{0000000000000}_{13}666\underbrace{0000000000000}_{13}1.$$
In addition to being palindromic, it has $31$ digits which is of course $13$ backwards.

Comment: It appears that Is $1000000000000077700000000000001$ is prime also ?

Answer (score 5):

$$n^2 + n + 41$$

You can even change it to:

$$n^2 - n + 41$$

This gives primes for $n = 1$ to $n = 40$ (the first one has one less prime over the range for $n=40$).

There are variations that give 80 primes, but that formula has a 41 for 40 in a row, so easy to recall.

See many others at: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: You're on a roll!! +1

Answer (score 5):

> $\qquad\quad$ *`I'm looking for some largeish (>10,000) easy-to-remember primes.`*

$$1~234~567~891.$$

Comment: Alternatively, 23456789.

Answer (score 4):

Mersenne primes are pretty easy to remember... e.g. just remembering that 7 generates a double Mersenne gives you the 38-digit prime $2^{2^7-1}-1$. For smaller (but still "largeish") examples, $2^{17}-1$ and $2^{19}-1$ give 6-digit primes.

Answer (score 4):

31,
331,
3331,
33331,
333331,
3333331,
33333331 (7 threes).
The next one is divisible by 17.